# How to stop the animation when you click the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is the animation of the chat tabs. When switching from the tab the tab which has already started the animation, but not over, fails.

```js
$(".tabgroup > div, .tabgroup .massage").hide();
$(".tabs a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
    tabgroup = "#" + $this.parents(".tabs").data("tabgroup"),
    others = $this.closest("li").siblings().children("a"),
    target = $this.attr("href"),
    athersTarget = $(".tabs a").not(this).attr("href"),
    massage = $(target).find(".massage");
  others.removeClass("active");
  $this.addClass("active");
  $(tabgroup).children("div").hide().removeClass("active");
  $(tabgroup).find(".massage").hide();
  $(target).show().addClass("active");
  $(massage).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i++) * 1000).show(500);
    $(".massageList, .custom-scroll_inner").animate({
      scrollTop: 9999
    }, 1000);
  });

});
// Auto show first
$(".tabs li:first-of-type a").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabgroup" id="first-tab-group">
  <div id="tab1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="massageList scrollbar-inner">
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="massageList scrollbar-inner">
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" style="display: none;">
    <div class="massageList scrollbar-inner">
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab4" style="display: none;">
    <div class="massageList scrollbar-inner">
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
      <div class="massage">massage</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="tabs" data-tabgroup="first-tab-group">
    <li>
      <a href="#tab1" class="active">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab4"> Tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How to stop the animation in a closed tab?
That would be for inactive tabs animation would be reset or stopped.

Comment: How about `$(".tabs a").stop(true)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop current animations with the `.stop(`) function.

In your case, you would do something like:

```
others.find(".massage").stop(true, true);
```

Stop takes in 2 optional arguments, the first is whether to clear the animation queue, and the second is whether to stop all animations immediately or let them finish. The default for both is false, but you want everything stopped immediately, so pass in true. If you want the existing message to continue fading out, just pass true in the first parameter.

https://api.jquery.com/stop/